# Traefik 2.0 IPWhitelist for TCP - Kubernetes CRD

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, kubernetes-ingress, traefik-ingress

We are using Kubernetes along with Traefik 2.0.
We are using Kubernetes CRD (IngressRoute) as provider with Traefik.

From Traefik Documentaion, it doesn't look like Middlewares can be used for TCP routers.

We would like to use [IP Whitelist middleware](https://docs.traefik.io/middlewares/ipwhitelist/)  with TCP router , but so far it's been working with  Http Router only.

Here is our ipWhitelist definition:

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: Middleware
metadata:
  name: testIPwhitelist
spec:
  ipWhiteList:
    sourceRange:
      - 127.0.0.1/32
      - 192.168.1.7
```

Here is Traefik Service Definition:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: traefik

spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      name: web
      port: 8000
    - protocol: TCP
      name: admin
      port: 8080
    - protocol: TCP
      name: websecure
      port: 4443
    - protocol: TCP
      name: mongodb
      port: 27017
  selector:
    app: traefik
```

IngressRoutes defintions:

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: simpleingressroute
  namespace: default
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - web
  routes:
  - match: PathPrefix(`/who`)
    kind: Rule
    services:
    - name: whoami
      port: 80
    middlewares:
      - name: testIPwhitelist
---
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRouteTCP
metadata:
  name: ingressroute.mongo

spec:
  entryPoints:
    - mongodb
  routes:
  # Match is the rule corresponding to an underlying router.
  - match: HostSNI(`*`)
    services:
    - name: mongodb
      port: 27017

    middlewares:
      - name: testIPwhitelist
```

Is there any way of restricting IPs with traefik TCP router ?

For more resources on the traefik with Kubernetes CRD  you can go [here](https://docs.traefik.io/routing/providers/kubernetes-crd/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, Middlewares can't be used for TCP routers. IPWhitelist through Middleware concept is acceptable only for HTTP router.
You can follow issue on [github](https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/5680) requesting middlewares for TCP routers.

Comment: I switched to [istio gateway](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/v1alpha3/gateway/). Looks like Traefik  has poor documentation & support